Sign In failed in for Javascript Email, FB login
I am working on a Javascript-based website. I integrated Firebase Google and Facebook SignIn. Everything was working fine. After 3 months, when I checked again. Firebase Google and Facebook Sign-in starts failing. I do not understand what happened. I checked everything, firebaseConfig, project_id, and other things. Everything is okay. I cleared the cache and ran it on different browsers, however, it still failed.
One error that I get in the beginning is related with /__/firebase/init.json. "404(not found)". However, after that my browser shows the Google SignIn page and I signs In. But then in "onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {" it says, user is not Signed In.
import { getAuth, FacebookAuthProvider, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithRedirect, 
  getRedirectResult, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.14.1//firebase-auth.js";

//Google SignIn button click
googleSignIn.addEventListener('click', async()=>{

  console.log('Google button clicked');
  await signInWithRedirect(auth, googleProvider);

  getRedirectResult(auth)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access Google APIs.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    
    console.log("token is");
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;

    createFireStoreUser(user.uid, user.displayName);

    // IdP data available using getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
    // ...
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    console.log("error is");
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.customData.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
  });

});


Not sure if it's related, but did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices?

@FrankvanPuffelen. I checked this page. They have written "Ensure that your web server can respond to https:////auth/ and https:////firebase/init.json." However, I still do not understand because this is handled by Firebase. For Facebook provider, they wrote this "The updated URI to authorize looks like https:////auth/handler — the trailing //auth/handler is important."
